# User input in default constructors (C++). Can this be done?

Tags: c++

This was the question: Write a program in C++ to enter two sequence separately and find total length of both sequences using constructor.
This is the program that I wrote. It runs but did I use constructors properly? Can we do this? Can we take user input in default constructors?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
class merge {
    private:
    int i;
    char seq1[5];
    int len, len1, len2;
    char seq2[5];
    public:
    merge();
};
merge::merge() {
    cout << "Enter first sequence: ";
    cin >> seq1;
    cout << "Enter second sequence: ";
    cin >> seq2;
    len1 = strlen(seq1);
    cout << "Length of first sequence: " << len1 << "\n";
    len2 = strlen(seq2);
    cout << "Length of first sequence: " << len2 << "\n";
    strcat (seq1, seq2);
    cout << "Merged sequence: " << seq1 << "\n";
    len = strlen(seq1);
    cout << "Total length: " << len;
}
int main() {
    merge o;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide info on how the sequences are presented? Comma separated (`1,2,3`)? Space separated (`1 2 3`)? Range (`1-3`)? Etc.

Comment: That can be done, but I wouldn't advise to do so. It unnecessarily couples your classes to the `std::cout` `std::cin` features, and make it less flexible for reusing it in a different program.

Comment: Tactical note: a constructor is generally a poor place to do user input or do anything other than initialization. For example, make an array of `merge`s and watch the fun and games. In this case it looks like you just want a plain old function, not a class.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp - We can input sequences like (aatta).

Comment: I am not sure what you are actually asking. Are you seeking for help to fix your code, or are you asking if it is a good idea to use the constructor to take user input in general?

Comment: @Srishti If that is an example input you have a problem: the array size is `5` and the input string length is `5`. This does not leave room for the trailing `\0`. Is there a reason not to use `std::string`?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 - The latter. Can we use constructors to take user input?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - Try to run this program and input five characters. It takes five characters. Even I was skeptical about this but someone showed me that we can do this. So I've been doing it. It doesn't work with string. Or I think I am doing it wrong. I am unable to input values into a string array. I don't know how to do that. If I did I would've used that. But since this char thing worked so I just rolled with it. I'll try to figure out how to input values into a string array.

Comment: @Srishti what you're encountering is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Because all programs that ensure there are no out of bounds accesses would be penalized by mandatory tests for out of bounds accesses, there are no tests. Should a flawed program access out of bounds, the results are undefined. Someone could write library support to perform tests, Microsoft sometimes does in the debug versions of their libraries, but typically in the name of speed, the program just keeps accessing off the official end of the allocation and maybe you see bad results.

Comment: Maybe you don't. Maybe you see them sometimes but not others. Maybe you see bad results a few hours or days after. Maybe years. Maybe never. Maybe you always see exactly what you expect right up until suddenly you don't. The only way to avoid uncertainty is to always remain in bounds.

Comment: Here's your code with a couple extra outputs to help you see what's happening: https://ideone.com/63ygzA The implementation here is checking for buffer overflows and slaps the program down hard. But you could get a line like *first sequence: abcdefghijkl* What's that box? Where'd the rest of the string go? It got written over by `len1 = strlen(seq1);` Huh. The box gets nuked by SO's parser. Makes sense since it's a garbage character..

Comment: @user4581301 Okay, thank you so much for explaining. I'll keep this in mind while working with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> User input in default constructors (C++). Can this be done?

Technically yes. Constructor body is mostly the same as any other function, and I/O is possible.

Practically, I/O in a constructor would be a bad design.

So we can, but we do not do this.

Comment: Ohhhh. So we can do this but this is not the purpose of a constructor?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we take user input in default constructors?

Yes you can do it, but you shouldn't.

There are many ways to explain why. For example, consider what it means to be default-constructible. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible) about the named requirement *DefaultConstructible*:

> Specifies that an instance of the type can be default constructed.
>
> **Requirements**
>
> The type T satisfies DefaultConstructible if
>
> Given
>
> ```
> u, an arbitrary identifier
> ```
>
> The following expressions must be valid and have their specified
> effects
>
> - `T u`   The object u is default-initialized
> - `T u{}`     The object u is value-initialized or aggregate-initialized.
> - `T()` / `T{}` A temporary object of type T is value-initialized or aggregate-initialized.

Your `merge` is *DefaultConstructible*. But is it really?

---

Consider what happens when you add a second constructor:

```
merge::merge(std::string seq1, std::string seq2);
```

Now I can choose whether I want to use the default constructor to take input from user, or get the sequences from elsewhere and call the other constructor. Sounds good, no?

(It isn't. It just helps me to emphasize the problem with your default constructor in the following examples. Bear with me.)

Code that is fine with a default constructible type `T`, but not quite with your `merge` is...

**example std::vector**

```
   using T = merge;

   std::vector<T> v(10);
   v[0] = T("1,2,3,4","4,5,6,7,8");
   // ...
```

Because I want to avoid reallocations of the vector and because I know that `T` can be default constructed, I created a vector with `10` elements even though I want to create the actual elements only later. I didn't want to ask for user input 10 times when I wrote `std::vector<T> v(10);` but thats the only way to resize a vector that contains elements of your class.

**example: std::map**

```
std::map<int,T> m;
m[1] = T("1,2,3,4","4,5,6,7,8");
```

I want to add an element to the map (if it didnt exist before). `std::map::operator[]` tries to find an element with the given key (`1`). It does not find one, hence it inserts a new element with that key and a default constructed `T`. Then it returns a reference to that `T`.
I could have used `insert`, but I was lazy and used `[]`. As a consequence, this code asks the user for input, but thats not what I wanted.

---

Here is a demo of the two issues I tried to explain above: https://godbolt.org/z/fj5qoa

---

Formally, your `merge` is default-constructible, but for most practical purposes it isn't. A default constructor is expected to construct an object in a default state. Reading user input is surprising and many types and algorithms that require that your type is default constructible will not work as expected, even though you provided a default constructor.