# C++ User interaction in classes

Tags: c++

In first semester CS when I had procedural programming the lecturer always told not to mix program functionality and interaction with the user in the same functions.
Now I have object oriented programming and I am confused how to implement interaction with the user in the classes.

Here I started coding a project that lets the user solve math equations and I wrote a class 'Task' like this. Is it a bad practice in object oriented programming to mix input/output with the rest of the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <tgmath.h>

using namespace std;

enum operation{
    add, sub, mult, divis, random
};

class Task{
    private:
        int min;
        int max;
    public:
        Task(int mi, int ma){
            min = mi;
            max = ma;
        }
        void setIntervall(int mi, int ma){
            min = mi;
            max = ma;
        }
        int getRand(){
            return (rand() % ((max-min) + 1)) + min;
            int min = max / 10;
            return (rand() % (max - min)) + min;
        }
        void printTask(operation op){
            if(op == random)
                op = (operation)(rand() % 4);
            if(op == add)
                cout << getRand() << " + " << getRand() << endl;
            if(op == sub)
                cout << getRand() << " - " << getRand() << endl;
            if(op == mult)
                cout << getRand() << " * " << getRand() << endl;
            if(op == divis)
                cout << getRand() << " / " << getRand() << endl;
        }
        bool checkifRight(double result);
};



int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));

    Task Task(15,100);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no inputs, so you are fine...

Comment: note that this question is borderline opinion based, though there are good reasons to not mix input with other logic (whether procedural or OO). Here is a similar question, though it was specifically asking for taking input in the default constructor https://stackoverflow.com/q/66247188/4117728

Comment: the simple rule is: a class should do one thing. If a class does something and reads input from the user then thats already two things (aka too much)

Comment: Note: code after `return ..;` is not executed (for `getRand`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cout << something` is not exactly "interaction with the user", it just informs the user of something, so this is ok  I think. And as you have no input in your code, you are fine so far.

But there is no sense in having multiple if statements in a row to check which operation is being use, use `else if` instead.

Comment: I changed the function and forgot to delete the line :)

Comment: @Hohlkopf okay ! and cool name ! Are you german ? Because, I am !

Comment: I am from lithuania but I used to live in germany for 7 years, after moving I still like the language :)

Comment: @Hohlkopf okay, in my case german is my, er, born / maternel / original language (I don't know how to say it right). But I don't know which language of French, English, German, Russian or Polish I like the most !